# Check method signature before creating delegate

Tags: c#, reflection

I have two delegates. I want to use reflection to load an assembly/classes and to go through each class to see if the static methods in the class match the delegates.

I got everything up to getting all the methodinfos but i can seem to find any method to check if it matches the delegate and i really dont want to try create and catch exceptions.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [CreateDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdzt99sk.aspx) method:

```
// The delegate type you want to match against
var delegateType = typeof(Func<int>);
// The method info
MethodInfo someMethodInfo = ...
var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, someMethodInfo, false);
if (del != null) {
    // you've got a match
}
```

Comment: Cool beans so the createDelegate will just return null. thanks its a no brainer now

Comment: Wasn't checking if a delegate matches a given MethodInfo without catching exceptions what you were looking for?